# How can I gift an iPad app from iPhone OR via Web?

Tags: ipad, itunes

I would like to gift an iPad app to my friend. I don't have iTunes installed on my work laptop and right now I don't have my iPad with me.

All I am trying is checking it on App Store on my iPhone, but the search is not listing the iPad version, instead it's only showing iPhone version of the same app.

I also tried via browser, but no luck.

Do I have to wait until I go home and do it from either iTunes on my Mac or iPad?

Looking for some solution!

Comment: Be aware that you can only gift to people in the same region as yourself: specifically to people whose iTunes account's credit card is issued in the same country as yours! (This might not be a big deal in US but it certainly is in Europe.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, you have to use iTunes to gift an application for iPad.

If the application is universal, then you can gift the app with your iPhone.